# Intel and Nvidia. How run both on desktop. Not bumblebe!

Tags: nvidia, video, intel

I have my desktop with two video adapters (Intel and Nvidia 210) I want use them both the same time. Is this possible?

They are actually works on the same time but Nvidia works with artefacts (nouveau driver) then Intel card enable. Resume from hibernate not work at all. Any chance have both card without issues?